# Checking if the input starts with a number and ends with an Upper letter

Tags: java, string, methods, java.util.scanner, digits

I don't know why this isn't working cause the value of they is still 0 even if I type a sentence that starts with a number, contains "end", and ends with an Upper case letter. Also, this should be case sensitive.

```
if (sentence.startsWith("[0-9]") && sentence.contains("end") && (sentence.endsWith("[A-Z]"))) {
    y++;
}
System.out.println(y);
```

Comment: Could you provide sample input

Comment: Here's the code I've written // Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); int no=0; while (no<4) { System.out.println("Type a number >4"); no = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine()); } scan.nextLine(); String sentence; int y =0; for (int i=0; i<nr; i++) { System.out.println("Type.."); sentence=scan.nextLine(); if (sentence.startsWith("[0-9]")&& sentence.contains("end") && (sentence.endsWith("[A-Z]"))) { y++; } } System.out.println(y) } }

Comment: String.startsWith() takes a String, not a pattern. Likewise endsWith().

Comment: @Jane I mean sample input like `1endH` not the code to verify the input has ord end

Comment: Since you want to check the first *character*, you could use `Character.isDigit`. Also, the last charscter could be checked with `Character.isUpperCase`. Note that both methods follow the Unicode definition of 'digit' and 'uppercase'.

Comment: But I'm using Strings not char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code didn't work because [String::startWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) doesn't take a regex as a parameter while you are using a regex. You need to use [String::matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) as shown below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int no = 0;
        while (no < 4) {
            System.out.print("Type a number >4: ");
            no = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        }
        String sentence;
        int y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
            sentence = scan.nextLine();
            if (sentence.matches("[0-9]+.*end.*[\\p{javaUpperCase}]")) {
                y++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Type a number >4: 5
Enter a sentence: Hello world
Enter a sentence: 123 Hello World ends with LD
Enter a sentence: 123HelloendHH
Enter a sentence: Good morning
Enter a sentence: 123Good morning
2
```

Comment: I don't think you need the $ at the end of the pattern if you use matches.

Comment: You are right. It will work without it as well. I've updated it.

Comment: It works when I copied and pasted your class, but when I changed it on my code ( the if part with yours ) it still shows 0. Idk whyy, :///

Comment: @Jane - I've updated the answer as per your code. Feel free to comment in case of any further issue/doubt.

Comment: I accepted it because it worked on its own, which means some code that I wrote myself was wrong, not what you wrote. So your answer works. And thanks a lot btw

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Due to their overhead I try to avoid using `regular expressions` unless it really simplifies the task.  In this case there are methods that facilitate the process.

In addition, white space at the beginning and end of the sentence affects the result (i.e. is not trimmed).

```
int lastIdx = sentence.length()-1;
if (Character.isDigit(sentence.charAt(0))
        && sentence.contains("end")  
        && Character.isUpperCase(sentence.charAt(lastIdx))) {
           y++;
}
```

Comment: You may add that this matches the Unicode definitions of 'digit' and 'uppercase', i.e. also other scripts than Latin may have digits and uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

See this REGEX `(^[0-9]+)(end)([A-Z]+$)` start with one or more digits and ends with one or more upper character

```
    if (sentence.matches("(^[0-9]+)(end)([A-Z]+$)")) {
        y++;
    }
    System.out.println(y);
```

Comment: Does the sentence contain the word `end`?

Comment: If not contains `end` this leads the condition to be `false`

Comment: Yes, it contains ends. When i try it with only the "end" condition, it works (y's value is increased) but not for the other two conditions.

Comment: Edit your pot and add input example

Comment: With matches you don't need the ^ and $.